# Why are people in "The Duh-Vinci Code" so low-tech?

Tags: futurama

In ["The Duh-Vinci Code" (S6E5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Duh-Vinci_Code), if all the people on that planet are so intelligent why are they are making wooden machines of everything?

Answer (score 5):

In that episode, Da-Vinci's home world is actually quite advanced. The things made of wood are the "stupid" Da-Vinci's inventions.

Here is an example of someone mocking Da-Vinci on his home world: "I have to draw in pencil, because I don't know how to use rendering software."

That quote shows that Da-Vinci is in fact the only one who uses low tech items and invents low tech things. The planet just has a renaissance building style (and the people are dressed in renaissance style clothes), which is why it may seem low tech. But, if you take a closer look their planet is quite advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they do it because wooden machines cause less pollution.

Answer (score 0):

They travelled in space and time back to the Renaissance.

Comment: What evidence is there that there was any time travel done?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies with a fundamental question, and we're not talking clown fundamentals here. The question is, "Why are we here?" The purpose of living is the deepest and most thought provoking question of our time and the population of "Duh"Vinci's world have an intriguing answer.

Through rigorous study and intense contemplation the so called "low-tech" society has discovered and embraced the solution to life's most mysterious mysteries. This involves living a life that does not consume unnecessarily. They realized, way ahead of their time I might add, that the "natural" progression of a civilization leads to waste and eventually ruin.

The more enlightened way to live involves using renewable resources, in this case wood. It involves the secrets to eternal youth, think about the fact that more than a thousand years have passed and the inhabitants are still in a state of physical perfection. It involves not living beyond your means and perpetuating the species without condemning them to a life not worth living. (sound familiar?)

Either way if you don't like or understand this answer then you obviously need a trip to "Duh"Vinci's planet to educate yourself.